# How to define ResourceManage in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, resources

I have one mvc project with resource file, this's name space in auto-generated file `Designer.cs`: `namespace eWarranty.Languages`

In my source code, I create new `ResourceManager`:

```
var resourceManager = new System.Resources.ResourceManager("eWarranty.Languages", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

But I get this error: `Additional information: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.`

I think my `ResourceManager` incorrect. How to define a wright instance of `ResourceManager`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the class of the resources when instantiating the ResourceManager.

Use

```
"eWarranty.Languages.Resources"
```

This is assuming the namespace is "eWarrenty.Languages" and the type name of the compiled resources is "Resources".

Hope this helps,